# Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined at causesDataService.js:56 at causesDataService.js:64

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

A little background. I created an ASP.MVC web app using SQL database for users and "causes" which can be added to the web app. the following faults are coming up. I will faults and code.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
at causesDataService.js:56
at causesDataService.js:64


Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
at _mixins.js:2
at _mixins.js:7

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Ok so now below code.....:::

MIXINS

```
var _mixIns = (function () {
    _.mixin({
        numberWithCommas: function (value) {
            return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
    });
}());
```

Cases Data Service::

```
var httpVerbs = {
    POST:'POST',
    PUT: 'PUT',
    GET: 'GET',
    DEL: 'DELETE'
};

var causesDataService = (function () {
    var ds = {
            commit: function (type, url, data) {

                // Remove 'id' member to perpare for INSERT
                if (type === httpVerbs.POST) {
                    delete data['id'];
                }

                return $.ajax({
                    type: type,
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
            },

            del: function (data) {
                return this.commit(httpVerbs.DEL, '/api/causes/' + data.id);
            },

            save: function (data) {

                var
                    type = httpVerbs.POST,
                    url = '/api/causes';

                if (data.id > 0) {
                    type = httpVerbs.PUT;
                    url += '/' + data.id;
                }

                return this.commit(type, url, data);
            },

            saveImage: function (data) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: httpVerbs.POST,
                    url: '/causes/uploadimage',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    data: data
                });
            },
        };

    _.bindAll(ds, 'del', 'save');

    return {
        save: ds.save,
        saveLocal: ds.saveLocal,
        saveImage: ds.saveImage,
    }

})();
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a reference to some other library that puts `_` onto the global scope. Perhaps underscore.js? Show where you include the JavaScript files on your page, and where these two files are listed within it.

Comment: @krillgar

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) ................ in relation to ............

 $(function()){

Comment: You don't need that `)` before the `{`.